# Could not find Che's application server

Tags: eclipse-che

I am trying to run Eclipse Che on my machine. I am getting error saying " Could not find Che's application server."

Environment: Windows 7 64bit
**Steps Followed:**
Install: Java,Maven,Docker Toolbox -> click the last check(Install Virtual Box with NDIS5 driver)  box also

Build latest git code, when I try to start tomcat from
 cd che/assembly/assembly-main/target/eclipse-che-/eclipse-che- then run  "che.bat".
I looked into : https://github.com/eclipse/che/pull/347/commits but no success.

---

I get below error, I blocked and any pointer will be helpful.

```
!!! !!! Could not find Che's application server. !!
```

#

On Windows, Che projects can only reside in %userprofile% due
to limitations of Docker. On this computer, %userprofile% is
C:\Users#############################################################

Could not find an existing docker machine.
Creating docker machine named default... Please be patient, this takes a couple minutes the first time.
Successfully started docker machine named default...
Setting environment variables for machine default...
Docker is configured to use vbox docker-machine named default with IP 192.168.99.101...

######## HOW TO CONNECT YOUR CHE CLIENT

After Che server has booted, you can connect your clients by:
1. Open browser to http://localhost:8080, or:
2. Open native chromium app.

#

!!!
!!! Could not find Che's application server.
!!!

Looks like something went wrong. Possible issues:
  1. (Win | Mac) VirtualBox not installed          ==> Rerun Docker Toolbox installation
  2. (Win | Mac) Docker Machine not installed      ==> Rerun Docker Toolbox installation
  3. (Win | Mac) Docker is not reachable           ==> Docker VM failed to start
  4. (Win | Mac) Docker ok, but docker ps fails    ==> Docker environment variables not set properly
  5. (Linux) Docker is not reachable               ==> Install: wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh
  6. (Linux) Permissions not properly set          ==> Che must run as UID 1000 with user in docker group
  7. Could not find the Che app server             ==> Did /tomcat get moved away from CHE_HOME?
  8. Wrong version of Java found                   ==> Che requires Java 1.8
  9. Did you use the right parameter syntax?       ==> See usage

We have seen issues with VirtualBox on Windows where your VM gets corrupted when your computer is
suspended while the VM is still running. This will appear as SSH or ethernet connection issues. This is
rare, but if encountered, current known solution is to uninstall VirtualBox and Docker Toolbox, and then
reinstall.

Che Environment Variables:

(REQUIRED) JAVA_HOME                             ==> Location of Java runtime

(REQUIRED: WIN|MAC) DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH  ==> Location of Docker Toolbox

(REQUIRED: WIN|MAC) VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH        ==> Location of VirtualBox

(OPTIONAL) CHE_HOME                              ==> Directory where Che is installed

(OPTIONAL) CHE_LOCAL_CONF_DIR                    ==> Directory with custom Che .properties files
  (OPTIONAL) CHE_LOGS_DIR                          ==> Directory for Che output logs
  (OPTIONAL) CHE_DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME               ==> (Win | Mac) Name of VM created by docker-machine
  (OPTIONAL) CHE_CONTAINER_NAME                    ==> Name to apply to Docker container if using -i option
  (OPTIONAL) DOCKER_MACHINE_HOST                   ==> (Linux) Docker host IP - set if browser clients remote

Usage:
  che [OPTIONS] [run | start | stop]
     -i,        --image              Launches Che within a Docker container using latest image
     -i:tag,    --image:tag          Launches Che within a Docker container using specific image tag
     -c:name,   --container:name     Sets the container name if -i provided; default=che
     -p:port,   --port:port          Port that Che server will use for HTTP requests; default=8080
     -r:ip,     --remote:ip          If Che clients are not localhost, set to IP address of Che server
     -g,        --registry           Launch Docker registry as a container (used for ws snapshots)
     -m:name,   --machine:name       For Win & Mac, sets the docker-machine VM name; default=default
     -s:client, --skip:client        Do not print browser client connection information
     -s:java,   --skip:java          Do not enforce Java version checks
     -s:uid,    --skip:uid           Do not enforce UID=1000 for Docker
     -t,        --stop-container     If stopping Che, will also stop Che container if Che ran with -i
     -h,        --help               Show this help
     -d,        --debug              Use debug mode (prints command line options + app server debug)
     run                             Starts Che application server in current console
     start                           Starts Che application server in new console
     stop                            Stops Che application server

The -r flag sets the DOCKER_MACHINE_HOST system environment variable. Set this to the IP address of the node
that is running your Docker daemon. Only necessary to set this if on Linux and your browser clients are not
localhost, ie they are remote. This property automatically set for Che on Windows and Mac.

#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a Che committer and we just made some changes to the che scripts and containers yesterday. Did the Docker hello-world run correctly for you?

If so, can you try going through the getting started steps again and re-downloading the scripts?

https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/che-getting-started

Comment: Thanks, I will try. Yes, docker hello world run correctly.